Office365 connectors within Teams will be deprecated
Today we started seeing this message in Microsoft Teams:

Action Required: O365 connectors within Teams will be deprecated and
notifications from this service will stop. Learn more about the timing
and how the Workflows app provides a more flexible and secure
experience. If you want to continue receiving these types of messages,
you can use a workflow. Set up workflow

We used this feature in Azure Devops Server (on premise) to send Build and Release notification to Teams. When looking for alternatives to do the same with Power Automate/Workflows there seems to be only the Connector to Azure Devops Services, not for Azure Devops Server (on premise).
Is there any solution within Power Automate/Workflows I have overlooked? Or are there any other simple solution to send these notifications to Microsoft Teams?

For anyone having the same problem, we solved this by using Power Automate.
After digging some more we found Power Automates Webhook, which we could trigger by using Azure Devops Server integrated Service Hooks with Web Hooks. These send the build/release info in JSON, which can be parsed in Power Automate. The variables where then used to create a message or adaptive card to send into Microsoft Teams.
Not the easy solution it was before and it seems to require the Premium Subscription of Power Automate, but at least it works.

I believe that is the recommended solution by MS. Is that correct?

They recommend using Power Automate, but with the Azure Devops Connector, which is for Azure Devops Services. Have not found a way to use it with Azure Devops Server (On Premise).
